# example of a sequence $x_n$ such that the set of limit points of $x_n$ is $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a sequence $x_n$ such that the set of limit points of $x_n$ is $[0,1]$.

I know the answer is $\mathbb{Q}$ intersection $[0,1]$, but how can I prove that?

Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Exactly, @DuaaHamzeh, it is customary that when you ask a question, you provide the other users with some of the work you've done. Otherwise you could be just not making your homework deliberately. Here is a set of rules: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  
Anyway, welcome to MSE!

Comment: Thank you for your note, I will take it into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationals in $[0,1]$ are countable, so they can be enumerated as a sequence $\{q_n\}$. Since the rationals in $[0,1]$ are dense in $[0,1]$, its limit point set is the whole $[0,1]$.
The only step you need to finish is the denseness property. Now observe that any point $x$ in $[0,1]$ has a decimal representation $x=0.a_1a_2\dots$. Then each $x_n=0.a_1a_2\dots a_n$ is rational, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. So $x$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set. A sequence in $X$ is  function from $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$

Take $X=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$

$X$ is countable and hence we have a bijection from $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$

Now use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, any countable dense sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $[0,1]$ can satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Another sequence is $\{ \sin^2(n)\}_n$ whose limit point set is $[0,1]$. The set $D:=\{m+2\pi n : m,n\ are\ integrs \}$ is dense in $R$. Hence for suitabilly chosen sequence $\{a_n\}_n$ from $D$ one can converge the sequence $\{\sin^2(a_n)\}_n$ to $\sin(x)$ for any $x\in R$.